# How to display an image in the BottomNavigationBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to display an image in the navigation bar like this:
[image]

but I can't because NavigationBarItem class needs an icon, so when I use ImageIcon widget I lose the colors. There are multiple colors in the image.

How to show the image in there or a way to make a colorful icon?

And when I use

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: ImageIcon(
                  NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
                ),
                title: Text('Image'),
              ),
```

it look like colored rectangle [image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
ImageIcon(
 AssetImage("images/icon_more.png"),
 color: Color(0xFF3A5A98),
 ),
```

instead of

```
new BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: Icon(Icons.home),
           title: Text('Home'),
         ),
```

change to this

```
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: ImageIcon(
               AssetImage("images/icon_more.png"),
                    color: Color(0xFF3A5A98),
               ),
           title: Text('Home'),
         ),
```

Comment: my problem is that my image has multiple colors in it so what you suggest is just  filling my image with one color

Comment: then instead of png use jpg file with preset colors

Comment: If you want to use an image but not have it change to the highlighted/deselected color then use Image.asset for your icon, if you want it to function like a normal icon where it changes color then use ImageIcon()

Answer (score 0):

As @asbah-riyas mentioned it can be done by providing the `ImageIcon` widget to the `icon` argument of `BottomNavigationBarItem`. Although you don't need to specify the `color` in it

You can check or play with it in [codepen here.](https://codepen.io/shubhamtanwar23/pen/pojGPex)

Comment: Actually it works on that site but when I try the same code in my app it is not working it shows just a gray rectangle instead of the image

Comment: can you provide the screenshot

Comment: @AsbahRiyas I updated the question so the screenshot is there

Answer (score 0):

so apparently the solution is to use Image.asset('image_path') for icon/activeIcon in BottomNavigationBarItem if you want to display images as bottom bar navigation icons *with original color*.

However, it does give an error if your `items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[]` has the keyword `const` in it. If you remove it you should be able to use `Image.asset` instead of `ImageIcon` (which tints to color)

Answer (score -1):

The NavigationBarItem's image property needs a Widget, not an Icon, so I could just use this.
`BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset('images/symbol.png')),`

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset('images/symbol.png')),

Provided you place your png image is images folder and mentioned  same as  images/image.png in your pubspeq.yaml under assets

Answer (score -1):

You can use this instead:

```
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Image.asset(" your image here "),
    ),
label: 'home',
),
```